# How do I retrive the value of the constant of a constraint in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `NSLayoutConstraint` constraint that looks like this:

```
var myConstant:CGFloat = 20

var myConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint (item: image,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: nil,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: myConstant)
    self.view.addConstraint(myConstraint)
```

When an UIButton is pressed, the image gets resized, therefore the constant of the image changes.

```
self.image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8)
```

Though, when I print the value of the constant after the transformation finished, the constant stays the same as it was before:

```
println(constraintImageCharacterHomeLeading.constant) // 20
```

Why is that happening? I resized the image, hence the constraint must vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transforms and Auto Layout don't work well together. If you set the transform of a view, it is expected behavior for it to NOT update the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

```
myConstraint.constant
```

It will do the job for you.

Comment: Thanks! I resized an `UIImage` using `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` but the `constant` of the constraint didn't change. Why?

Comment: This answers the question in the title but doesn't address the OP's real question.